# How to change vertical pills to horizontal tabs on small screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following vertical pills menu. When the screen is large, it displays nicely.  When the screen is small, the it takes up too much space.  Is there any way to change it to a horizontal tab when the screen is small?  I googled but couldn't find any examples.

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
     <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
       <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
       <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
       <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
       <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-9">
     <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
       <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">first</div>
       <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">second</div>
       <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">third</div>
       <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">forth</div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Any pointers very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you more concerned with vertical to horizontal orientation, or changing the actual pills to tabs?

Comment: Hi Zim, actually both.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to change the vertical to horizontal orientation of the nav. You'd use
`flex-sm-column` instead of `flex-column` to that the nav reverts to it's natural `flex-direction:row` on the smallest screens.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="nav flex-sm-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">first</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">second</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">third</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">forth</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/XfRu8lX5z3)

If you want to change the `nav-pills` style to `nav-tabs` style it would require a lot of extra CSS.

Comment: the code doesnt change anything.  I had my browser at max and min and the pills show up only as stacked vertical.  Is it supposed to change?